Verifying the Existence of a Linear Functional with Prescribed Values on a Linearly Independent Set in a Normed Space
Let $\{x_1, \dots, x_n\}$ be a linearly independent subset of a normed vector space $X$, and let $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n \in \mathbb{R}$. I want to prove that there exists a bounded linear functional $x^* \in X^*$ such that $x^*(x_i) = \lambda_i$ for each $i = 1, \dots, n$.
Rough Approach:

Since $\{x_1, \dots, x_n\}$ is linearly independent, I can define $x^*$ on the finite-dimensional span of $\{x_1, \dots, x_n\}$ by setting
$$
   x^*\left(\alpha_1 x_1 + \cdots + \alpha_n x_n\right) = \alpha_1 \lambda_1 + \cdots + \alpha_n \lambda_n.
   $$
This definition is well-defined because of the linear independence of the set.

By the Hahn-Banach theorem, I can extend this linear functional $x^*$ from the span of $\{x_1, \dots, x_n\}$ to the entire space $X$, ensuring that the functional remains linear and bounded.

Finally, I would verify that $x^*$ satisfies $x^*(x_i) = \lambda_i$ for all $i = 1, \dots, n$.


How should I approach the problem to fill the details regarding the above in order for the solution to be mathematically rigorous? Are there any additional considerations or subtleties I should address?

No change needed. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solution-verification: For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is my proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.
